# Problems installing software with apt-get

Tags: apt

I am running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and I would like to install FSLView. I cannot install it through Ubuntu Software Center, and when I try installing the package via the command line with `sudo dpkg -i fslview_4.0.0~beta1-1~nd12.04+1_amd64.deb`, I get a simple error:

> Errors were encountered while processing:  fslview

`apt-get upgrade` tells me:

```
09:58:29 Downloads > sudo apt-get upgrade Reading package lists... Done Building dependency tree        Reading state information... Done You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these. The following packages have unmet dependencies:  fslview : Depends: neurodebian-popularity-contest but it is not installable
           Depends: libqt4-qt3support (>= 4:4.5.3) but it is not installed
           Depends: libqtassistantclient4 (>= 4.6.3) but it is not installed
           Depends: libqwt5-qt4 but it is not installed
           Depends: libvtk5.8-qt4 but it is not installed
           Recommends: fslview-doc but it is not installable
           Recommends: qt-assistant-compat but it is not installed
           E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
```

What does "is not installable" mean? If I do `apt-get -f install`, FSLView only gets removed. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install the missing dependencies manually, then try to install FSLView again. `is not installable` means that the package is not available in the repositories. You have to get and install the `neurodebian-popularity-contest` package manually like you did with `fslview`.

Luckily there seems to be a [package source](http://neuro.debian.net/debian/dists/precise/) for it that even contains `fslview`. Edit your `/etc/apt/sources.list` and add those line:

```
deb http://neuro.debian.net/debian/ precise contrib main non-free
```

After that you're going to have to install the repositories key:

```
sudo apt-key adv --recv-key --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com A5D32F012649A5A9
```

After that you can try installing `fslview` using `apt-get`:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install fslview
```

If I haven't missed anything this should work.

Comment: Hi André, Thanks for your reply. Installing worked like a charm. However, I do get an error when I try to run fslview, but I believe this may be due to some incompatibilities between fslview and Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. This is the error I receive: fslview: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt3Support.so.4: undefined symbol: _ZNK14QWidgetPrivate17hasHeightForWidthEv